# android set home wallpaper using intent from drawable

Tags: android, android-intent, drawable, wallpaper

I'm kind of new in android developing and i want to set  home wallpaper with drawable image .
i wrote this code for setting but don't work and in visual android device at first i have dialog but next when i click as background i get this message :

> "you need to insert sd card  before using camera ..."

also i need use my drawable as  source of images ...
here is my code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String mimeType = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpg");    
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("@drawable/wall_7");         
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/jpeg" );
intent.putExtra("mimeType", mimeType);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);      
this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Set as"),200);
```

and i going to have a slidable wallpaper , not a fix image . i'm using this intent bcs it let user crop image .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to add this permession to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Then you can use this to set it using the wallpaperManager :

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MyActivity.this); 
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper_img);
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Or you can use  [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html)
to set the wallpaper using intent

Answer (score -3):

You can directly set background in your xml file using android:background tag.Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: The question is about setting device home wallpaper image and not for setting a background image for an activity.